# Grinding noise when braking after fitting new pads and discs

Tags: toyota, brakes, brake-calipers, brake-pad

Just fitted my own pads and discs to both front wheels for the first time. Driver's side is fine but passenger's side makes a slight grinding noise when I brake. The caliper on the passenger side was fairly corroded and the pistons wouldn't push back without opening the bleeding valve a little (yes I had the cap off the master reservoir). The driver's side is absolutely fine and the pistons receded easily.

Is it possible I've just not got something lines up quite right or do I need a new caliper?

Could my caliper be rubbing my disc?

What could be the source of the grinding noise?

Comment: What is the make/model/year of your vehicle?

Comment: Toyota MR2 MK2 1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the noise when applying the brakes, and if the pads are aftermarket, sometimes they make noise until they get worn a little since sometimes the material they used to cover the pad may not be the best one :)

Comment: I did wander if that was the case. Got the same pads and discs on the other wheels with no noise. Wasn't sure how long to drive with the noise before deciding if just bedding in or an actual problem.

Comment: Did you check that wheel for bearing problems? May be that the bearing is specially suffering when braking (happened to me once), otherwise the bearing was kinda ok.

Comment: Noise seemed to clear up on the way to work this morning. Will continue to keep an eye on it though.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that only one side makes the noise, one reason that I can think of (but i cannot pronounce a sure answer as it should be checked physically and visually by a mechanic) is that the piston on that side does not retract to its position after releasing brake due to wear. Another thing that i can think of is the wheel bearing, though it should sound crunchy even while not on the brakes, some cars have bearings integrated in the brake disc, and it might just be the case of a faulty one. Head over to a local garage and have someone inspect it, it's the only safe way to find your answer.

Edit: upon re-reading, the piston not retracting is your most certain culprit

Comment: Also make sure that you didn't put the brake pad in backwards ;)