# Girinding noise /sticking breaks even after installing new caliper, rotor and pads

Tags: camry, brake-calipers, grinding, break

I installed both new caliper, rotor and pads in my 2005 Toyota Camry 2.4 L on the front. Though driver side breaks are making grinding noise.

After installation it was ok for 3-4 miles of driving then driver side breaks started making noise.

Noise aggravates while pushing paddle and noise continues even after releasing paddle.
While pushing paddle, noise is continuous grinding and after releasing noise is  periodic grinding.

Can anyone help me figure out where the problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grinding noise when braking after fitting new pads and discs](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/grinding-noise-when-braking-after-fitting-new-pads-and-discs)

Answer (score 2):

I made a fool of myself. I took my car to a mechanic and he said I had placed one of the brake pad front-side-back.